# AWS Machinelearning Error: "Exceeded threshold for number of bad records"

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have written a piece of code that takes data from S3 (amazon storage service) and creates a datasource from it. This datasource will be used for creating a machine learning model.

My issue is that I get the error message: "Exceeded threshold for number of bad records", whenever I send try to create the datasource.

NOW the real headscratcher! I do NOT get the error when I create the datasource in my own account and with my personal AWS keys. **I only get the error when I attempt to use my firm's aws account**. I have confirmed that the problem does not lie within the S3 bucket policy.

Thanks you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue.
dataLocationS3 was wrong. The Firms bucket had several objects in it and therefore my location was wrong.